# Replace text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to replace text using Javascript.  It's a little different than the other ones I've seen on S.O. because the text that needs to be added in is an incrementing integer.

For example:  Replace the string: "John Mary Ellen Josh Adam" with "John1 Mary2 Ellen3 Josh4 Adam5"

Comment: So what precisely do you want to do? Append a number to each word, where "word" is defined as consecutive alphabetical characters, separated by white spaces?

Comment: how you know you have to add the integer.. if there is a space can you add it. What is the condition tocheck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a callback replacer:

```
var str = "John Mary Ellen Josh Adam", i=0;
str = str.replace(/ /g,function(m) {i++; return i+" ";});
```

EDIT: Noticed that won't add a number after "Adam". That can be fixed just by adding:

```
i++; str += i;
```

at the end of the code.

EDIT2: Or all-in-one:

```
str = str.replace(/ |$/g,function(m) {i++; return i+m[0];});
```

Comment: About adding a number after "Adam": you could also adjust the regex to match the end of the string, e.g. `str.replace(/ |$/g, ...`.

Comment: That would add an extra space on the end, though, because of what the function returns.

Comment: I liked this - especially the elegance of it - but felt it better to use the jsfiddle option rather than adding in an extra line of code.  Perhaps that's just my inexperience.

Comment: you could also match the words instead of the spaces, see my answer. That way `John  Mary` (two spaces) yields `John1  Mary2`, not `John1 2 Mary3`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
var array = string.split(" "), i, j;

for(i=0,j=array.length,string="";i<j;string+=array[i]+(++i)+" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "John Mary Ellen Josh Adam";

var i = 0;
var output = input.replace(/\w+/g, function(m){ return m + ++i });
```

output is:

```
"John1 Mary2 Ellen3 Josh4 Adam5"
```

Comment: Couldn't `RegExp.lastMatch` be replaced with the 1st parameter passed to the callback?  Which is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I put together this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SgN5n/) for you.

This is the code:

```
var originalStr = "John Mary Ellen Josh Adam";
var splitStr = originalStr.split(' ');
var newStr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++)
    newStr += splitStr[i] + (i+1) + ' ';

alert(newStr);
```

Comment: Please include the code in your answer as well as some explanation.

Comment: This results in a trailing space on the string.

Comment: i agree @robmisio, that shouldn't be happening

Answer (score 0):

I quickly hacked this up.  Not sure how efficient it is, but it works.

```
var x = 1, str = "John Mary Ellen Josh Adam",
newStr = str.replace(/\b([^\s]*)\b/g, function(i){
    return i && (i + (x++));
});
```